# Class library that can be shared between .NET Framework and .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a big class library written in .NET 4.0 but when I reference it in a Store App that uses .NET Core, it shows an error. And further, Microsoft just released .NET Core for the next version of .NET.

I want to know what type of project will be able to be shared by both .NET 4.6 and .NET Core? Is a class library able to do that?

It seems that the release of .NET Core specialized for Store Apps causes confusion for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a PCL (Portable Class Library) that works for Metro apps, it will definitely run on the fully fledged .NET (aka, your normal ASP.NET, WF, WPF applications).

That means that you don't have to do anything, besides porting your existing library to be compatible with the PCL you choose.

Comment: If you are going to leave an answer at least consider fixing the tags first.

Comment: That's fine but my point remains the original tags where [tag:.net] and [tag:asp-classic] this is because when writing in the hint box the OP wrote `asp .net` this should tells us two things - **1.** They meant to write `asp.net` so it should be tagged [tag:asp.net] and **2.** [tag:asp] is a synonym of [tag:asp-classic] which has no relevance to the question and should be removed. The fact I added [tag:.net-4.0] is irrelevant, I was just adding more context to the question as the OP refers to .Net 4.0 directly in the question.

Comment: Sorry @patrick it is not an attack at you I'm just getting sick of clearing these questions from the [tag:asp-classic] queue, I even updated a question [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272481/692942) about it recently which seems to be being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new target called `dotnet` which you can use to target the platforms DNX, UWP and .Net 4.6. Effectively, this libraries are build against .Net Core packaged libraries instead of the libraries of the full .Net Framework.

Read more here: https://oren.codes/2015/07/29/targeting-net-core/ and related posts.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks. I will remember. But I think the reply is kind of an answer already :)